# Verify Gauss divergence theorem $\iint_S xz dydz + x^2y dzdx + y^2z dxdy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Verify Gauss divergence theorem, for $$\iint_S xz dydz + x^2y dzdx + y^2z dxdy$$
where $S$ is the outer side of the surface in the first octant formed by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$, the paraboloid of revolution $z=x^2+y^2$, and the coordinate planes.

Considering $\vec F=xz\,i+x^2y\,j+y^2z\,k$, we have $div \vec F=z+x^2+y^2.$

By Gauss divergence theorem, $$\iint_S\vec F.d\vec S=\iiint div \vec F\, dV=\iiint (z+x^2+y^2) dxdydz $$

Suggest the limits and remaining part, please.

[image]

Comment: What coordinates should you be using?

Comment: @TedShifrin Any coordinate system, Cartesian, Spherical or Cylindrical...

Comment: I meant: In this particular problem, what would be the convenient and intelligent choice?

Comment: May be Cylindrical?

Comment: @TedShifrin Would you be so kind as to help with the solution, please?

Comment: The problem is not clearly worded. We assume that they mean that the volume in question is in the first octant ($x,y,z\ge 0$), bounded on the sides by $x^2+y^2=1$, and bounded above by $z=x^2+y^2$. Now set up the integral in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you.. what will be the limits of integration in that case?

Comment: Seeng a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4485789/949989) of yours that is $1.5$ years old and where you made much better attempts to find limits, I find that an astonishing question.

Comment: Okay, thank you

Comment: You can thank me after you have shown your attempts. One does not learn from being spoon fed.